# Create a Spring Search DTO with defined list

Tags: spring, spring-boot, validation

Is it possible to create a DTO with validation tag which accepts only defined list of values? For example:

```
@Getter
@Setter
public class SearchParams {

    private String title;

    @NotNull
    private String type; // type can be only 'approved', 'new' and 'closed'
}
```

Is there some way to use tags to have only this strict list of values?

Comment: If you use enum instead of String?

Comment: Can you show me code example, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@Getter
@Setter
public class SearchParams {
    private String title;

    @NotNull
    private TypeEnum type;

}

public enum TypeEnum {
    APPROVED,
    NEW,
    CLOSED
}
```

You can enrich the enum with a description in order to have control on the case sensitiveness

```
public enum TypeEnum {
    APPROVED("approved"),
    NEW("new"),
    CLOSED("closed");

    private String desc;

    TypeEnum(String desc) {
        this.desc = desc;
    }

    public String getDesc() {
        return desc;
    }

    static TypeEnum fromDesc(String desc) {
        TypeEnum[] values = TypeEnum.values();
        for (TypeEnum typeEnum: values) {
            if (typeEnum.getDesc().equals(desc)) {
                return typeEnum;
            }
        }
        
        return null;
    }
}
```

So you can get the relevant enumeration via a lowercase String as:

```
TypeEnum.fromDesc("new") // this will return TypeEnum.NEW
```

Comment: is this case-sensitive? is it possible to add validation message?

Comment: You can write your own validators over enumerations, you can check here: https://www.baeldung.com/javax-validations-enums